# nodejs. How to send http request trough HTTP CONNECT tunnel?

Tags: node.js, sockets

There's an example of using HTTP CONNECT tunnel from node.js documentation.

```
  var options = {
    port: 1337,
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com:80'
  };

  var req = http.request(options);
  req.end();

  req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
    console.log('got connected!');

    // make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
                 'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
                 'Connection: close\r\n' +
                 '\r\n');
    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
    socket.on('end', () => {
      proxy.close();
    });
  });
```

Is there a way to use the socket with established tunnel with http library instead of passing http request body trough socket by myself (trough socket.write)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the regular `http` library has any proxy support, so you'll have to implement it yourself.

The [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) package (built on top of `http`) will make things a bit easier, though:

```
const request = require('request');

request({
  url    : 'http://www.google.com',
  proxy  : 'http://localhost:1337'
  tunnel : true
}, (err, res, body) => {
  ...
});
```

By specifying [`tunnel : true`](https://github.com/request/request#proxies), it will also tunnel plain HTTP requests.